# Adding month to calculated value

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, date-time

I want to created a calculated column where I add 3 months to a date. This is what I have so far.

```
=DATE(YEAR([Last updated]); MONTH([Last updated])+3; DAY([Last updated]));
```

SharePoint produces and error saying that my code is incorrect, if anyone has any ideas that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are on an english environment, so the separator is , (comma) and not ; (semi-colon)

```
=DATE(YEAR([Last updated]), MONTH([Last updated])+3, DAY([Last updated]) )
```

More functions and syntax: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

Along with Danny's suggestion (comma instead of semi-colon), it turns out that I was using a Date/Time column type with a Calculated value instead of using a Calculated Column.

Once I started using this, I didn't receive any further issues.

Comment: Then you can mark (your own) answer so it is removed from that very long unanswered queue